# how to handle tooltips on onmouseover in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

In a web page, tooltip is designed by mouseover with a function call, I am unable to handle this in selenium

```
<tr><td align="left" class="BoldFont">Pending&nbsp;Payments</td>
 <td align="right" id="pendingBalance"><a href="#" onmouseout="closePopup();" onmouseover="displayHelpPopup(this,arrHelp[20][0]);"><span class="BoldFont">$0.15</span>  </a>  </td> </tr>
```

if we put mouse on $0.15 it shows the tooltip like "Pending payment".
this test case need to automate but am unable to do, Please Can any one help me

Comment: How do you want to `handle this` ? Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_ , your code trials and error stack trace (if any).

Comment: added html code

Comment: What exactly you mean by `test case need to automate`? Can you update the question with the _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: tooltip automation testing with selenium

Comment: So do you want to verify that the tool till is changing to "Pending Payment" or not when hovering on $0.15?

Comment: yes, by selenium logic